# How to Associate 5 atmost pictures with a account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `model Company` which `has_many :company_pictures` but at most 5 photos. I have to show user all 5 file field for image uploading.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_pictures
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_pictures
end

class CompanyPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>"}
end
```

controller code

```
def new
    @company = Company.new
    5.times { @company.company_pictures.build }
end
```

Now through this in new form I am able to show 5 file field. Now on submit . let say now my form did not get saved because of any other error. now I find only those file field that hold some value with that. i want to make sure that user will always able to attach at most 5 photos whether he is creating a new company or updating a company.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in this cases is that before presenting the user with the "new" layout, I create and save the object first in the database with a "draft" status with the objective of getting a primary key and be able to save the pictures (the pictures need a primary key in order to be saved). Then, when the user submits the form, no matter if there are errors or not I always save the pictures and then present the user with the form, the errors (in case there are) and since the images got saved to the database you can display them to the user.  If there are no errors just remove the "draft" status from the user and continue your workflow.

Now the question is, what do we do with all those drafts ?  Create a rake task that run's every hour and delete all the records in this state.

Comment: i only want to create picture only when my company saved